# Creating new *.reg file

Tags: windows, registry

I want to add network authentification capabilty. I have to add two keys in the registry and would like to send a *.reg file to co-worker, who need to enable this feature on Windows XP. It took not to much time to find, how such file looks like inside and I created a file containing this code:

```
REG ADD HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa /v "Security Packages" /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "tspkg"
REG ADD HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\SecurityProviders  /v "SecurityProviders" /t REG_SZ /d "credssp.dll"
```

But there are already keys in `"Security Packages"` and `"SecurityProviders"`, will they be replaced or will my keys just added? I know - it's called "add", but I would like to ask beofre testing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will add the key if it doesn't exist and update the key if it already exists

Comment: Do I need something more in the file or it is already the whole file?